# ModuleNotFoundError: cannot import local file

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a module with multiple files structured like this:

```
/bettermod/
├── __init__.py
├── api.py
├── bettermod.py
├── errors.py
└── loggers.py
```

From `bettermod.py`, I'm trying to import two things:

- a class called `API` from `api.py`
- the whole `errors.py` file

For the first thing, it is quite easy, I just have to do this:

```
from .api import API
```

However, for importing the whole `errors.py` file, I'm encountering a problem; I'm trying to do like this:

```
from . import errors
```

which should work, according to this [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), but it's raising the following error:

```
  File "/path/to/bettermod/bettermod.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import errors
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bettermod'
```

Edit: when debugging, I found that `__name__` was equal to `bettermod.bettermod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module.

I cannot tell you what is wrong with certainty, but there is a smell: `bettermod` package has a `bettermod` module. You want to do `from bettermod.bettermod import MyBetterClass`? I doubt it. In Python files ARE namespaces, so choosing your file and directory names is also an API design. Just keep that in mind.

I suspect the problem is masked by the name collision. Try this. If you run `python` in `bettermod` directory and say `import bettermod` you are importing `bettermod\bettermod.py`. And `.` is relative to the `bettermod.py` module. Now try to run `python` in directory above `bettermod` package directory. It will work because now `.` resolves to `bettermod` package.

Try:

```
import mymodule
mymodule.__file__
```

This will tell what `mymodule` is. For packages, it will show path to `__init__.py`. This will help you to orient yourself. Also look up `PYHTONPATH` and how you can use it to make sure you are importing from the right path.

Answer (score 0):

here is good tutorial how to fix https://fortierq.github.io/python-import/

with next file structure

```
project
└── src
    ├── db
    │    └── models.py
    └── scripts
         └── script.py
```

For me worked next construction in `script.py`

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path


path_root = Path(__file__).parents[1]
print(path_root)
sys.path.append(str(path_root))

from db.models import Station
```